# When I run the js code in chrome‘s console,but I get different print

Tags: javascript

The print is different,why?

the first part, I get 1,2

```js
var a = 1;
console.log(a);
function a(){}
a = 2;
console.log(a);
```

the second part,I get two function a(){}

```js
var a = 1;
if(true){
  console.log(a);
  function a(){}
  a = 2;
}
console.log(a);
```

Comment: The function's assignment to the variable name is hoisted to the top of the block, but not to outside the block.

Comment: Because in second part if condition block act as a scope for defination of a as function